# Passing a variable number of arguments to a function in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function that uses `*args` to accept a variable number of arguments. I want to, similarly, *pass* a variable number of arguments (say, from a list or tuple). How does this work in Python?

For example, if I have

```
def product(*args):
    res = 1
    for x in args:
        res *= x
    return res
```

and a list `a`, how can I use this function to get the product of all the values in a list, without having to write out `product(a[0], a[1], ..., a[N-1])` longhand?

I understand that I could just write the function to accept a single list argument, but I want to understand how this works in general.

I was only able to solve the problem by dynamically generating code and using `eval()`. Surely there's a better way?

Comment: You can explode a slice: `product(*a[:3])` <-- this will have the same effect as `product(a[0], a[1], a[2])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Aside from this being a common duplicate - please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to be much more direct, clear, explicit and **not conversational**. I edited the question to show an example of good style for Stack Overflow questions. In particular, while it's good to [do research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), the question should only show results from research that are **relevant to understanding the question**. (Also, because this is not a discussion forum, we do not have "threads" here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is [also used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/) to unpack an iterable into individual arguments.

Given the definition of `product`, calling with a list is as simple as:

```py
print(product(*[1,2,3])) # 6
```

Comment: Though the question is a duplicate, I put effort into cleaning up the Q&A because I suspect that it can make a good signpost.